# Codeigniter error select query fails to check user input

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeigniter,and I am using 3.1.5 version. Below is my user login function.

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        // Load Login View
        $this->load->view('login');
        // validate form
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[5]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()== true){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            // check user in database
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("users");
            $this->db->where(array("username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $user_data  = $query->row();
            // check if user exists or not
            if($user_data->username){
                // show temporary success message
                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","User successfully logged in");
                // set temporary sesstion variables
                $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user_data->username;
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Invalid username, user not exist");
            }
        }
    }
```

When i provide user credentials like username and password I am getting the below error and not able to solve this.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 29

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci315\application\controllers\Auth.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci315\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

The line number 29 exactly from here

```
      if($user_data->username){
       // show temporary success message
       $this->session->set_flashdata("success","User successfully logged in");
         // set temporary sesstion variables
         $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $user_data->username;
         }else{
         $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Invalid username, user not exist");
         }
```

If i comment the above section then there is no error. Please suggest me where I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used below code this working fine. used if($query->num_rows() > 0) instead of
if($user_data->username) and $query->row()->username instead of $user_data->username

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        // Load Login View
        $this->load->view('login');
        // validate form
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[5]');
         if($this->form_validation->run()== true){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            // check user in database
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("users");
            $this->db->where(array("username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                // show temporary success message
                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","User successfully logged in");
                // set temporary sesstion variables
                $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $query->row()->username;
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Invalid username, user not exist");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)